Length of Longest Subarray With A Consistent Frequency
Given an array A, a subarray of A is called "consistent" if the maximum occurrence of all elements in the subarray is equal to the minimum occurrence of all elements in the subarray. Find and return the length of the longest consistent subarray from A.
Example:
For A = [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3], the longest consistent subarray is [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3], so the answer would be 6.
Let A = [4,5,1,7,5,7,1], the max subarray would be [5,1,7,5,7,1], returning a length of 6.
What would be an efficient approach to solve this problem? I'm not sure what time complexity should be aimed for.
Constraints:
n = array.length
1 < n < 10^5
1 < array[i] < 10^9

I tried to find a question like this on leetcode but the closest was:
https://leetcode.com/problems/length-of-longest-subarray-with-at-most-k-frequency/description/
Here's a potential solution using binary search that I tried and failed at:
public class Solution {
    public int solve(int[] A) {
        int l = 0, r = A.length, k = 0;
        while (l < r) {
            int m = (l + r) / 2;
            k = verify(A, m);
            if (k == -1) {
                l = m;
            } else {
                r = m;
            }
        }
        return k;
    }
    public int verify(int[] A, int m) {

        for (int i = m; i < A.length; i++) {
            int[] extr = getExt(A, i - m, i);
            if (extr[0] == extr[1]) {
                return m;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public int[] getExt(int[] A, int l, int r) {
        int[] out = new int[2];
        HashMap<Integer,Integer> freq = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = l; i < r; i++) {
            freq.put(A[i], freq.getOrDefault(freq.get(A[i]), 0) + 1);
        }
        int max = 0, min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        for (int k : freq.values()) {
            max = Math.max(k, max);
            min = Math.min(k, min);
        }
        out[0] = max;
        out[1] = min;
        return out;
    }
}



Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please see: How do I ask and answer homework questions?
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Earlier you said your approach was too slow. How do you know what's too slow? How fast is fast enough?

Well I just had a sense that I had an unnecessary amount of operations. I'd say a tier better than brute force would be good. Brute force in this case would be O(n^3) where you would try each possible subarray (n^2) and check if it's consistent (nk where k is the different frequencies). My approach was wild.

So you're not submitting this somewhere and get a "time limit exceeded"? Where is this from?

I should have mentioned. This was from an online interview. I forgot to copy the question description and my attempt, but I tried to put all the details I could from memory. When i tried my answer it didn't tle but it was either incorrect or infinite loop.

O(n^2) runtime: I use growing windows from each starting point and count the values in the window, also keeping track of the largest count. And the equivalent criterion that the largest count multiplied by the number of different window values is the window length.
def solve(A):
  R = 0
  for i in range(len(A)):
    c, C = Counter(), 0
    for r, a in enumerate(A[i:], 1):
      c[a] += 1
      C = max(C, c[a])
      if C * len(c) == r:
        R = max(R, r)
  return R

Attempt This Online!
Your binary search btw can't work, as you're trying to do binary search over something non-monotonic. For example for your array [1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3], lengths 4 and 6 are possible, but length 5 is not.

Nice solution! I'm curious, since you're just moving the starting point is there a way to have it where you don't have to use a new counter each time?

@EmmanuelPierre I guess I could alternate between growing and shrinking. Grow from the first value to the end, then remove the first value and shrink backwards from the end to the second value. Then grow from the third, and so on. But it would complicate keeping track of the largest count (or an alternative to that). I did write some other optimizations, but nothing spectacular, so I chose the simplest/nicest one. Given the limit n < 10^5, I suspect there might be something with a better worst case complexity class anyway (but I don't see it).

It is very likely that you misread the problem.
As I read from somewhere else, the original problem asks: maximum occurrence of all elements in the subarray is equal to "the minimum occurrence of all elements in the whole array (rather the min of subarray)". This can be solved with dynamic sliding window in O(n) time.
In general, when n is large (e.g., 1e5), we should aim for O(n) or O(nlogn) time complexity.

Yea I realized this after my friend had the same problem.
